# Spring Boot not fetching correct data from Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My code is as follows: 
Repository:

```
@Repository
@Component
public interface SearchInventoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Inventory, String>{

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from ORACLE_DATA1")
    List<Inventory> findAllDatabases();

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select count(*) from ORACLE_DATA1")
    int getCount();
}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class GetInventoryService {

    @Autowired
    private SearchInventoryRepository searchInventoryRepository;

    public List<Inventory> findAllDatabases()
    {           
        return searchInventoryRepository.findAllDatabases();
    }

    @Autowired
    public int getCount()
    {
        return searchInventoryRepository.getCount();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@Component
public class GetInventoryController {

    @Autowired
    private GetInventoryService getInventoryService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/getAll")
    public List<Inventory> getAll()
    {
        return getInventoryService.findAllDatabases();
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/getCount")
    public int getCount()
    {
        return getInventoryService.getCount();
    }
}
```

The following queries yield the correct result when I run them in SQL developer:

```
select * from ORACLE_DATA1;
select count(*) from ORACLE_DATA1;
```

However, in the spring api, many of the results are duplicates, and many results are not fetched. The count of results, remains the same in SQL Developer as well as when fetched through the API.

I have never come across such an issue before. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using native queries? These queries are very simple and you should be able to use default methods `count()` and `findAll()` provided by `spring-data`

Comment: Also, why you have declared same method name in two different classes? you can directly call parent repository native query. Or keep different names and than try calling and see what happens.

Comment: Ditch your `findAllDatabases` method and use the `findAll` as from the `JpaRepository`. The same applies to your count, there already is a `count()` method defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There is no need to annotate with `@Repository` an interface that extends `JpaRepository`

2) It's not correct to annotate with `@Component` a class that already has a `@Repository`, `@Service` or `@Controller` annotation.

`@Component` simply marks the class as a bean, the others integrate this feature.

3) `@Autowired` is used to inject instances of the annotated type. This is **not** correct:

```
@Autowired
public int getCount()
{
    return searchInventoryRepository.getCount();
}
```

4) You can use the default methods provided by `JpaRepository` instead of using `@Query`. E.g.:

```
searchInventoryRepository.findAll(); // already defined
```

and

```
searchInventoryRepository.count(); // already defined
```

Comment: followed all of your points, but I am still encountering the same problem. Getting multiple entries of a single row, and many rows aren't even fetched. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @shasha0607 These out of the box methods should work well for your use case. It is very hard to speculate possible reason without knowing full detail. Would it be possible for you to create a sample repo in Github that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @shasha0607 are you sure that the *"duplicate results"* are really duplicates? Maybe you have them twice in your database. There is nothing wrong with the code if you've modified it as I said above.

Comment: I have checked my database and all entries in the table are unique.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you are using native queries, but JpaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository, and PagingAndSortingRepository extends CrudRepository, and this provides, and I quote:

`sophisticated CRUD functionality for the entity class that is being managed`

Example:

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
extends Repository<T, ID> {
                                                                                                                   (1)
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
                                                                                                                   (2)
T findOne(ID primaryKey);
                                                                                                                   (3)
Iterable<T> findAll();

Long count();
                                                                                                                   (4)
void delete(T entity);
                                                                                                                   (5)
boolean exists(ID primaryKey);
                                                                                                                   (6)
// … more functionality omitted.
```

}

Among the existing methods, there are two that do what you need. It is not good to reinvent the wheel.

You can get more information from this link
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html